# Limit of sequence of Lebesgue integrals over symmetric domains

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to show the following:

If $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ with $f$ nonnegative, then $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_{-n}^{n}tf(t)dt=0$$

I"ve shown that for every $n≥0$ we have $$
\frac{1}{n}\int_{-n}^{n}tf(t)dt≤\int_{-n}^{n}f(t)dt$$ but I'm not sure if that's useful or not. My aim is to employ one of the standard convergence theorems, but I'm not sure how to set it up so far.

Comment: The dominated convergence theorem should work, since $|\frac{t}{n}f(t)| \leq |f(t)|$ on $[-n, n]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f_{n}(t)=\frac{1}{n} tf(t)\mathbb{1}_{[-n,n]}(t)$ goes to $0$ pointwise and that for every $t$, we have $|f_{n}(t)| \le |f(t)| \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ because $f_{n}(t)=0$ for $|t|>n$. Then use dominated convergence.

Comment: Strange majoration ! Why $\frac{n+1}{n}$ ? Moreover, $f_n(t)$ is not positive, so add absolute values..

Comment: I was confused... you are completely right. I have written an answer now anyway so I will edit it